# Java. Универсальный класс для обработки разнотипных объектов

Tags: java, android-studio

Пишу игру.
Вопрос простой и касается основ, таких как абстракция и ,возможно, шаблоны.

Есть интерфейс для неактивного объекта. То есть объекта, который отрисовывается, может изменять форму, размер, положение на экране и т.п.
Вот его суть:

```
public interface IBasicObject {

         byte update(float dt);        

    float getX();           float getY();
    void  setX(float pX);   void  setY(float pY);

    //... дальше идут другие графические геттеры и сеттеры
}
```

Есть объект, реализующий данный интерфейс, называется BasicObject. Таки объекты используются для декора.

Есть так же интерфейс "живого объекта" вот такой

```
public interface IHealthObject extends IBasicObject{

        Body mBody = null;

        float GetHealth();
        int GetTypeOfBlast();
        Body GetBody();

        void ResetBody();
        void ReduceHealth(float healthToReduce1);
        void Kill();
    }
```

Ну и есть объект HealthObject, реализующий данный интерфейс, а заодно расширенный из класса BasicObject. Выглядит это так:

```
public class HealthObject extends BasicAnimatedObject implements IHealthObject
```

То есть HealthObject не только имеет все графические составляющие, но и может участвовать в коллизиях.

Сейчас у меня разные классы (на основе Array) для обработки каждого вида объектов. Как создать класс, который сможет хранить любой вид объекта (либо BasicObject либо HealthObject). При этом, обращение будет только к функциям, указанным в самом базовом интерфейсе - к Update(dt) и геттерам-сеттерам.

Comment: Любой объект который реализует BasicObject или HealthObject или другие производные от этих интерфейсов могут быть переданы как параметр (BasicObject basicObject)

Comment: Что в этом вопросе связано с проблемами работы IDE Android Studio?

Comment: Generics не рассматривали?

Answer (score 1):

Да есть шаблон, но не помню как называется. Простите за немного неадекватный код, но думаю суть из него будет ясна. Мы должны в этом классе работать именно с базовым интерфейсом.

**Класс Main**

```
/**
 * Created by Andrej on 18.10.2016.
 */
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IDoingSomethingWithAllObjectsImplementingIBasic iDo = new IDoingSomethingWithAllObjectsImplementingIBasic();
        iDo.addObj(new BasicObject());
        iDo.addObj(new BasicObject());
        iDo.addObj(new HealthObject());

        iDo.doSome();
    }
}
```

---

Класс **IDoingSomethingWithAllObjectsImplementingIBasic**

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Created by Andrej on 18.10.2016.
 */
public class IDoingSomethingWithAllObjectsImplementingIBasic {
    Set<IBasicObject> allObj = new HashSet<>();

    void addObj(IBasicObject obj){
        allObj.add(obj);
    };

    void doSome(){
        for(IBasicObject obj : allObj ){
            obj.doSamething();
        }
    };
}
```

Как видим, мы с помощью одного класса работаем с разными объектами. В последующем, при добавлении новых типов объектов, вам не придется менять данный кусок кода. Так как данный класс ничего не знает о реализациях. Для него главное это контракт - интерфейс. И любой класс, который реализует данный интерфейс обработается без проблем.

---

**Класс HealthObject**

```
public class HealthObject implements IHealthObject {

    int x,y;
    @Override
    public void doSamething() {
        System.out.println("Do do do... Health");
    }

    @Override
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    @Override
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    @Override
    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    @Override
    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

---

**Класс BasicObject**

```
public class BasicObject implements IBasicObject {

     int x,y;
    @Override
    public void doSamething() {
        System.out.println("Do do do... Bas");
    }

    @Override
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    @Override
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    @Override
    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    @Override
    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

---

**Интерфейс IBasicObject**

```
public interface IBasicObject {
    void doSamething();

    int getX();
    int getY();
    void setX(int x);
    void setY(int y);
}
```

**Интерфейс IHealthObject**

```
public interface IHealthObject extends IBasicObject {
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо.
Вчера сам дошел до этой идеи. Но думаю, вопрос пусть останется здесь - может кому пригодится. Мне было непонятно - как будет создаваться базовый класс с полем IBasicObject. То есть заранее не известно - сколько памяти будет выделено под данное поле, а значит неизвестно сколько памяти выделять под объект базового класса. Теперь я приблизился к пониманнию этого, однако все еще остается вопрос - можно ли инициализировать такое "интерфейсное" поле не в конструкторе базового класса, а в каком-либо методе?

Answer (score 0):

Я бы вместо IBasicObject,IHealthObject ввел несколько более частных интерфейсов (HasPosition, ..., HasHealth, Drawable)

Вы наследуете интерфейсы как обычно наследуют классы, не рекомендую этого делать, потому что теряется гибкость.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Да, я сам прихожу к той же мысли.
Наследование интерфейсов - плохая мысль. ТО же самое делается простои имплементацией обоих интерфейсов через запятую. При этом интерфейсы не связаны друг с другом. При этом сможет существовать объект, которому не нужен графический интерфейс, но нужен физический. 

Я все еще в сомнениях - к чему больше относятся координаты объекта - к его графической реализации или к физической. Теперь уже больше склоняюсь к физической. А графике оставить только данные о текстурных полигонах, а координаты для отрисовки передавать из физики.